# Disable hover state of a html tag

Tags: jquery, hover, state

I want to disable hover state of my html element but not using another css to override css of hover.

Here is my code lines:

```
<div id="test">
    Hello world
</div>

<style>
    #test {color: red; border: 1px blue solid;}
    #test:hover {color: green; border: 1px blue solid;}
</style>
```

in this case, 'Hello world' will be green when mouse over, but I want nothing happening when  mouse over and no adding/overriding a new css to disable hover. Is there any way to disable hover state by javascript/jquery?

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable hover state with this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').hover(
      function () {
        $('#test').css('color','red');
      }
    );
});
```